# How use curl in php?

Tags: php, curl

I am trying to use cURL.
I want to send a number via a POST request using cURL.
response site:
if number is wrong:  response: "sorry number is wrong"
if number is correct  go other page html.
I use the bellow code:

```
$number = "+98*******"; // enter a phone number
$data = array('phone' => $number);
$url = "https://example_page1/auth/login";
$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_REFERER, $referer);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $data);
$res = curl_exec($ch);


echo "\n" . substr($number, 0, -7) . "******* :" . $res; 
?>
```

The above code works properly.
when number is wrong: response:"*******: sorry.number is wrong"

when number is correct
is give empty page .
i want to go page 2 and give header ,...
but give empty page.
What is the problem؟

Comment: Check your error logs.

Comment: Also, don't forget to close your connection afterwards, `curl_close($ch);`

Comment: How does that page do redirection? Curl will only follow 3xx redirections in the head. If it is via javascript, you will have to do it yourself.

Comment: thanks. give: 500 error internal Server error

Comment: The fact that it gives a 500 error doesn't help much if we can't see the logs. Check the logs and see what it says.

Comment: The character encoding of the HTML document was not declared. The document will render with garbled text in some browser configurations if the document contains characters from outside the US-ASCII range. he character encoding of the page must be declared in the document or in the transfer protocol.

Comment: I do not have a lot of skills in php
How can I debug?